# Subtract Totals from 2 tables

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 Tables Deposit and Withdrawal

```
Deposit Table:
AccountNumber  Amount
1               200
1               400
1               150
           Total=750

Withdrawal Table:
AccountNumber  Amount
1               100
1               300
1               150
           Total=550
```

I need a query to sum the total for each table & Subtract (Deposit-Withdrawal) Group BY AccountNumber to be (750-550) = 200 something like:

```
TotalBalance Table:
AccountNumber  Amount
1               200
```

I have tried Karamafrooz Answer

Select SUM(d.Ammount) - SUM(w.Ammount)
from Deposit as d inner join WithDrawal as w
on d.AccountNumber=w.AccountNumber
Group by d.AccountNumber

### But i am getting wrong values

sorry for that, now i have a 3rd table calls Profit:

```
Profit Table:
AccountNumber  Amount
1               100
1               200
1               150
           Total=450
```

I need the total to be (Deposit+Profit-Withdrawal)
How can i do that? jim31415 solution worked perfectly for the 1st case

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, and why they didn't work.

Comment: I am new to sql server and i couldn't find a solution

Comment: You couldn't find a solution or you couldn't *try* anything?

Comment: Hell Fresh, you don't have to tell us WHY it didn't work, just the attempt is helpful. Leave that part out. They don't generally know why it didn't work, or they wouldn't ask questions.

Comment: @jcolebrand I copy and paste the close reason. I will truncate the part asking for why it didn't work.

Comment: Ok am sorry, i will try my best and post it here..sorry again

Comment: @jcolebrand I think "why they didn't work" actually means "how they didn't work" e.g. got an error message (and here it is!), nothing happened, the wrong rows were updated, the results weren't as expected (here's what they were, here's what I expected), etc.

Comment: Those extra few words makes a world of difference to someone with less than 50 rep showing up to this site for the first time @AaronBertrand and don't act like everyone should be uber-smart and read minds ;-)

Comment: @jcolebrand to be fair, Fresh copied the close reason pretty much verbatim. So perhaps you should appeal to meta to have the wording changed.

Comment: "copied the close reason" .. a) don't do that, b) you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This uses sub-query to get the totals for each account in each table. Then it sums the amounts. Notice that withdrawal amount is negated, **sum(-d.Amount)**.

```
select 
   AccountNumber,
   sum(Amount) as Balance
from (
   select d.AccountNumber as AccountNumber, sum(d.Amount) as Amount from Deposit d group by d.AccountNumber
   union
   select d.AccountNumber, sum(-d.Amount) from Withdrawal d group by d.AccountNumber
) as t
group by AccountNumber
```